# Error setting up texlive with texstudio

Tags: texlive, texstudio

I made sure no existing **texlive/latex** installations exist on my system, and I installed **texlive** manually using the installation script, by following instructions here:
https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Now I have the folder `/usr/local/texlive/2023/` on my system.

I appended `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin:$PATH` to `~/.bashrc`

I try to compile a minimalist tex file in Texstudio. I add the path `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin` to the `$PATH` field (Settings -> Build). But I get the error:

```
Process started: lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "basic sample".tex

warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/://share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c://texmf-dist/web2c://texmf/web2c.
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt lualatex.fmt
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/://share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c://texmf-dist/web2c://texmf/web2c.
/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt line 25.
Process exited with error(s)

Process started: makeindex "basic sample".idx

Input index file basic sample.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
Process exited with error(s)

Process started: lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "basic sample".tex

warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/://share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c://texmf-dist/web2c://texmf/web2c.
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt lualatex.fmt
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/://share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c://texmf-dist/web2c://texmf/web2c. /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt line 25.
Process exited with error(s)
```

It looks like it can't find the installed texlive files. How can I fix it please?

And do I need to run the script `/usr/local/texlive/2023/install-tl` at all?

Comment: Are you 100% the installation went well? Note that you usially do not need to set the PATH inside texstudio, buit adding it only to `.bashrc` is wrong! If you start texstudio from a menu or by double clicking on a file, then `.bashrc` have never been involved. I'd add it to `.profile` as well (then log out and in again). `.profile` is read at login at what it sets is seen by all subcequent processes. Also note that `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin` is not really relevant here on its own, there is only subfolder(s) in there.

Comment: You are right. I can get it to compile a tex document if I start texstudio from terminal (after adding the .bashrc export). But if I double click a file I get the error above, even though the `$PATH` variable in `settings > build` is set to `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux`. So thanks, I have a solution now! But I still wonder why texstudio won't find the path..

Comment: @ellat Which operating system do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure it you can pass two paths in the txs configuration. In my case, I have only `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/` and it works. Try it.

Comment: In addition, you have to insert the path in the Options>Configure TeXstudio>Build>Commands ($PATH) at very bottom of the window (make sure to enable advanced settings).

Comment: I tried it. Still won't work. I'm on textudio v.4.7.2. It's okay for now I can run it from terminal. Thanks very much.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm on Archlinux.

BTW, adding the path inside texstudio on another ubuntu machine works fine (v.4.2.1). But not on arch (which has the latest version of texstudio).

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path to the binaries in the `Commands` tab of the texstudio preferences?